# Plotly Express Timeline with Time x-axis in two formats

Tags: express, plotly, timeline

(EDIT: I did figure out that I don't need actual DATA in the added go.Scatter. My code is therefore slightly simplified now. )

I have a Plotly Express Timeline chart showing a set of activities, with the X-axis showing time in UTC format.

I want to add another X-axis at the top of the chart, showing time as a TIME DELTA from a particular fixed epoch. That fixed epoch is shown as a vertical bar in the plot. I simply want to show, using the top x-axis, where the activities fall in seconds from this fixed epoch.

After literally hours and hours, I have a solution which sort of works, but it feels dumb and has flaws.

1. I generate the timeline using px.timeline()
2. I add my vertical bar using add_vline()
3. In order to customize the final figure and add another x-axis, I
   needed to use make_subplots. I do this, then populate it with the
   data+layout from the px.timeline object.
4. Now, in order to get an x-axis2, I add a dummy trace using
   go.Scatter(). I don't need actual data in it. Just something to
   assign to x-axis2.
5. In order to get numbers onto the x-axis2 axis, I calculate the range for for the main x-axis first, and then I calculate the Time    in Seconds from the epoch, for those min/max times. I then use these min/max values for the range of x-axis2.

This looks ok initially, but the resulting plotly chart allows you to drag one x-axis with respect to the other, which doesn't make sense for this scenario. Also, if I use the 'autoscale' button in the chart, the two x-axes get slightly mis-aligned. (Also, it just feels dumb to have to add a Scatter plot, when I don't really have a second dataset. It is a single dataset, and I just want to show the time in two different formats.)

There must be some smarter/cleaner way of doing this?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(task="A", start='2023-01-01 01:00:00', end='2023-01-01 02:00:00'),
    dict(task="B", start='2023-01-01 02:00:00', end='2023-01-01 03:00:00'),
    dict(task="C", start='2023-01-01 03:00:00', end='2023-01-01 04:00:00'),
    dict(task="D", start='2023-01-01 04:00:00', end='2023-01-01 05:00:00'),
])


fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
fixed_epoch = dt.datetime.strptime("2023-01-01 02:33:00",fmt)


timeline = px.timeline(df, x_start="start", x_end="end", y="task")
timeline.add_vline(
    x=fixed_epoch, 
    line_width=2.5, 
    line_color="red"
)


data = timeline['data'][0]
layout = timeline['layout']

fig = make_subplots()
fig.add_trace(data)
fig.layout = layout

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(xaxis='x2',mode='markers',))

x_rmin = dt.datetime.strptime(min(df["start"]),fmt)
x_rmax = dt.datetime.strptime(max(df["end"]),fmt)
pad = (x_rmax-x_rmin)/16
x_range = [x_rmin-pad, x_rmax+pad]
x2_range = [(x - fixed_epoch).total_seconds() for x in x_range]

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='ACTIVITY TIMELINE ',
    xaxis =dict(
        position = 0, 
        title='UTC', 
        range=x_range,
        ),
    xaxis2=dict(
        position = 1, 
        title='Time from epoch (sec)', 
        anchor='free', 
        overlaying='x', 
        side='top', 
        range=x2_range,
        ) 
    )
fig.show()
```

[image: Timeline Chart]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, one of the issues with the current solution was that the Autoscale button would mis-align the two axes. I at least figured out a way to disable/remove that button from the interface to keep user from accidentally doing this.

```
fig.show(config={'modeBarButtonsToRemove': ['autoScale2d']})
```